# Get input and select box elements inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get all kinds of html elements inside a div. This time I am trying to get input type and select box in a div when I use the below jQuery selector.

```
$('#1 input, select')
```

*It is giving all the `select` boxes from other `div`s also.*

But I want to target only one div and get all kind of elements in that. How can I do it? Below is my code:

```
<div id="1">
    <input type="text" id="2">
    <select id="123">
        <option value="template">template</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="3">
    <input type="text" id="4">
    <select id="456">
        <option value="template">template</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="5">
    <input type="text" id="6">
    <select id="789">
        <option value="template">template</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

*it is giving all the select boxs*, As per your statement second selector `$('select')` which is performing behaving correctly and selecting all the `select` element in the document.

You need to set the context for `select` which can be done using various ways. like using [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector.

> Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

```
$('#1 :input')
```

*OR*

You can use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements,

```
$('#1').find("input,select")
```

*OR*, [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), Here use descendant selector individually

```
$('#1 input, #1 select')
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('input, select', '#1')`

Simplest way to find something inside a scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('div#1 input, div#1 select')
```